# Where do I set my SPF record for domain managed by Yahoo?

Tags: email, dns-servers, mx

Many years ago we purchased a domain from Yahoo. Now our website is hosted on Amazon EC2.

The output of an SPF checking tool (http://www.kitterman.com/getspf2.py) says:

> SPF records are primarily published in DNS as TXT records.
>
> The TXT records found for your domain are: i=182&m=bizmail-mx2-p9
>
> SPF records should also be published in DNS as type SPF records. No
>   type SPF records found.
>
> Checking to see if there is a valid SPF record.
>
> No valid SPF record found of either type TXT or type SPF.

Where do I get access to these values? Can somebody speculate, where can I find an interface, or a configuration file to fill in the missing fields?

**Edit**

To clarify, the domain name is managed by Yahoo and the actual server is an EC2 instances being routed via an elastic ip.

The best I could on the Yahoo control panel only mentions CNAME, A and MX. Where is SPF?

[Here's](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/smallbusiness/domains/domainfeatures/advanceddns/advanceddns-01.html) a Yahoo help article covering this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to publish those records with your DNS provider. If you don't know who this is, post your real domain in here and we can look it up for you.

Note however that not all DNS providers offer the ability to create TXT records; the only way to know for sure is to try it, or to call their support.

Comment: So, when I go to the Yahoo control panel I can set CNAME, A, and MX records. Nothing mentions TXT or SPF. See http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/smallbusiness/domains/domainfeatures/advanceddns/advanceddns-01.html

Comment: Well, Yahoo doesn't do this so the solution was to move to Route53.

Answer (score 2):

Yahoo doesn't allow it's users to add `TXT` records on their own.

You'll need to:

1) Send an email to yourself using the Yahoo ID associated with your domain

2) Contents of the email will include your request and the actual `TXT` record

3) Call Yahoo domain support and inform them that you want to add a `TXT` record... they'll ask you to do #1 & #2 above

4) Wait for your records to propagate and verify this with: http://www.kitterman.com/

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would publish these in the same places that you would setup your CNAME, A, MX, etc. records. Try looking there. This will be at your DNS level, so if you're hosting on Amazon E2C, I'd recommending sending a ticket into them, it may be something they have to do.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, see the above comment.

Comment: It's going to be where ever the DNS servers are located. I have the same options in my NameCheap control panel when it's not being hosted anywhere (adding the records to the domain) but once I have the site hosted somewhere, I have to use the DNS servers for that location. That, is where you need to work on this, not at Yahoo control panel, becuase your site isn't there. Go to your Amazon one, if you can't find anything, submit a ticket. If you'd like, submit a ticket to Yahoo as well, this will get their process of taking forever to respond to you going :)